# I am trying to enter a value using int to Arduino ESP32 from bluetooth and the value is read wrong,

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth, embedded, arduino-esp32

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
void setup() {
  SerialBT.begin("BTMODE");
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

}
int k;
void loop() {
   while (SerialBT.available()) {
  k=SerialBT.read();
  Serial.println(k);
   }
}
```

the above is my code and the outputs i get for entering 3 is : 51 13 10
what's to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are neither sending nor receiving an `int`.  `51 13 10` is a sequence of ASCII *characters* `'3' <carriage-return> <line-feed>`, which would be expected if you *typed* the string at a terminal for example.

You then receive individual characters and print thier *integer* value.

You either need to send *binary* data, and recombine the individual *bytes* into an integer (for which both sides would need to agree on both the size and byte order in an integer), or you read a *line* and interpret the string and a decimal representation of an integer.

For example:

```
void loop() 
{
    static char input[32] = "" ;
    static int input_index = 0 ;

    while (SerialBT.available())
    {
        char c = SerialBT.read() ;
        if( c != '\r' && c != '\n' )
        {
            input[input_index] = c ;
            input_index = (input_index + 1) % (sizeof(input) - 1) ;
        }
        else if( input_index > 0 )
        {
            k = atoi( input ) ;
            SerialBT.println( k ) ;
            input_index = 0 ;
        }

        input[input_index] = '\0' ;         
    }
}
```

Note that here also you can replace:

```
while (SerialBT.available())
```

with:

```
if (SerialBT.available())
```

since it is already in the `loop()`. Doing so may lead to more deterministic behaviour for other code in `loop()`, because it will only read one character per iteration rather than all available, which will take a variable amount of time to process.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Working Codes, Hope this will help you

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());  
  }

  int val = 0;    
  if (SerialBT.available() > 0) {
    while (SerialBT.available() > 0) {
      char incoming = SerialBT.read();
      if (incoming >= '0' && incoming <= '9') {
        val = (val * 10) + (incoming - '0');
        delay(5);
      }
    }
    //Select your Range  
    if (val > 0 && val <= 30) {
      Serial.print("My Value: ");
      Serial.println(val);
    }
  }
  delay(20);
}
```